# decrypt with more than one password

Tags: encryption, hash, cryptography, passwords

I'm searching for a specific way to encrypt my data.
I want to encrypt it with my password and decrypt it with that.
Later I want to gain other people access to chosen parts of my data with their passwords.

Is there any other way than to decrypt the data everytime I add a new "reader" and encrypt it all again with a "mix" of all passwords? 
And than the big question is how to decrypt without knowing the passwords of everyone?

And than I thought of another problem. How to validate that the given/login password is correct? 
I thought the following might work without saving the actual password or the encryption password:

- Get a password ; "Thats an amazingly bad password"
- Use the hash as encryption and decryption key ; hash(salt + "Thats an amazingly bad password")
- Save the hashed hash as validation for the password ; hash(hash(salt + "Thats an amazingly bad password"))

What do you think about it?

Thanks for help everyone

Comment: regarding the second question: what is the difference between "the actual password" and "the encryption password"?

Comment: What does "chosen parts of my data" mean? On a per file basis to part of a file or portions of a database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Encrypt the data once with a secure key such as random bytes.
2. For each user encrypt the above key using the user's password (properly extended), save that in a file or DB under the userID and a salted/hashed password for authentication.
3. To access lookup the user's entry verify the supplied password with the salted/hashed password, decrypt the data key with the user's password.
4. Decrypt the data with the data key and return to the user.
5. Side advantage: A user's password can be changed without changing the actual key the data is encrypted with.

For the second part:

Do not `hash(hash(salt + "Thats an amazingly bad password"))`,   use a password extension method such as PBKDF2 on the user supplied password for the encryption key. Such methods take a salt and a password and iterate many times to make the operation slow, somewhere around 100ms seems to be a good target.

Hashing a hash does not accomplish anything other than adding a trivial amount of time to the operation.

Comment: Those are great ideas! Thanks a lot!